How to start a qemu virtual machine and from the host, execute some commands to finally shut it down
I'm deploying virtual machines with qemu. Installed OS is Debian with linux kernel debian 6.8.11-amd64.
The way I deploy a vm is directly with qemu-system command (i.e no vm manager).
In a command fashion, I would like -from the host- to:

Start the VM
Execute a serie of command within the guest (git clone something, configure something, make something, execute something, return success!)
Shutdown the VM

I found that one can exchange with the VM through QMP using specific command,
(https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/interop/qemu-qmp-ref.html#id2)
But I cant find how to do my step 2. It looks like only a specific set of commands are authorized with QMP..
Thanks in advance,
Pierre

What image are you using to boot the virtual machines?

the original file is debian-12.2.0-amd64-netinst.iso. The format of the image I then created is qcow2.

You will need to build a custom filesystem image that includes scripts and/or some other tooling that will run your commands and power off the virtual machine. There are many ways to approach this problem.  Here's one possible solution:

Start with an operating system image. For this example, I'm using the debian 12 cloud image.

We'll create a copy-on-write clone of the image to hold our changes. This makes it easy to start over. Here we're creating a 5 GB image; you could adjust the image size as necessary for your workload:
qemu-img create -f qcow2 -F qcow2 \
  -b debian-12-genericcloud-amd64.qcow2 root.qcow2 5g


Now we need to embed some additional information in the image. For this example, we need a netplan file to enable DHCP, and an rc.local script that will perform our clone/build/install/etc actions.
I have a netplan file called network.yaml that looks like this:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: true

And an rc.local file that looks like this:
#!/bin/sh

set -e

while ! ping -c1 dns.google; do
  echo "waiting for network"
  sleep 1
done

apt-get -y update
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf automake libtool git autopoint gperf texinfo help2man

mkdir -p /srv/build
cd /srv/build
git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/hello.git
cd hello
./bootstrap
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
/usr/local/bin/hello

poweroff

We can use the virt-customize command to embed these in the image:
virt-customize -a root.qcow2 \
  --copy-in network.yaml:/etc/netplan/ \
  --copy-in rc.local:/etc/


Now we can use the qemu-system-x86_64 command to boot our image:
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1g -enable-kvm \
  -nographic \
  -serial mon:stdio \
  -drive file=root.qcow2,driver=qcow2 \
  -nic user,model=virtio-net-pci

This will run the commands in our rc.local file and power off the vm when complete.


If you need to explicitly report results back to the host, you again have lots of options. You could add a second serial port to your virtual machine (-serial file:status.txt) and write status data there (echo OK > /dev/ttyS1), or you could capture the console output to a file (replace -serial mon:stdio with -serial file:console.txt) and then grep the output when the vm complete, etc.
If you are concerned about the script not completing due to an error, you could wrap your qemu-system-x86_64 command with the timeout command. For example, to ensure the qemu vm exits in under 2 minutes:
timeout 120 qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1g -enable-kvm ...


Thanks for you complete answer! I will test it during the day!

In the end, the trick was to use the rc.local file and write it into the guest with the virt-customize command. Thanks a lot for your help and the completeness of your answer!

I may suggest as well the qemu-web-desktop that provides a browser based interface, and allows to ingest bash scripts in the boot process. There is as well a time-out setting.

Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. However, in its current form your post looks like a comment or possibly improvement to the accepted answer rather than providing a different solution approach. As such, it should probably be submitted as an edit suggestion to that answer.
